# The best way to attach a heatsink to a SMD component?

Tags: surface-mount, heatsink

There's a SoC I want to throw a heatsink on. What's the best way to do this for maximum heat transfer and longevity?

I know of thermal pads, thermal adhesive, and thermal paste -- but when it comes to the standard black plastic packages, I have no clue which of the options would be best.

Comment: Standard black plastic packages are not designed for applications with excessive power dissipation, they should be well cooled by PCB they are attached to. If a IC has the power dissipation that exceeds standard plastic package, the package usually has a corresponding thermal bottom slug, which is meant to be soldered down, and multi-layer PCB must be used with massive internal copper layers. If you need extra cooling, it means that either the PCB is wrongly designed, or you are using some overclocking. Throwing a heat sink is up to you, any method will work, depending on mechanical/vibration

Comment: which SoC package? and throw how by what W/'C spec?

Comment: @Ale..chenski This board was designed to be passive but I do want to make it dissipate heat better as I do want to perform some overclocking.

Comment: No decent design can be done without specs

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist it's a Exynos5422. I actually plan to do this on a handheld ham radio too, but need to identify the hot spot still.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist again, this is a really generic catch-all passive cooling question, as I asked about a heatsink on any SMD component made out of black plastic.

Comment: Epoxy is a thermal insulator unless designed with thermal pads.

Comment: @Saustin, you should not be trying to remove heat through the black plastic (epoxy), you should be removing heat through the copper leads. So the design of the copper leads will strongly impact your ability to do this.

Comment: Exynos5422 is a serious octacore prcessor, and likely requires a serious approach to extra cooling.

Comment: BGA, right?  Power-FET cooling for small smd packages is often done through the bottom of the board.  Perhaps consider a heatsink for a ceramic BGA package, but stuck on the underside of your pcb, using adhesive silicone pad.

Comment: Interesting -- so it would technically be better to put the heatsink on the bottom of the chip on the other side of the board, not on top of it?

Comment: @Saustin you claim this to be "generic catch-all passive cooling question", but missing the point of several comments above that SoC is _not_ generic IC. You need to study datasheet for thermal characteristics and recommended PCB design _just to make it work_ in standard operating range. Then you can make a guess what would be the best way to improve heat dissipation. Most likely it won't be a heatsink on top of the chip but rather beefed-up copper on PCB

Comment: @Maple it's a 676 pin BGA.  It would need an extra two layers for top and bottom heat spreaders leaving all traces buried in the internal layers.  And no space for thermal vias. And nothing to attach to the heat spreading layers.  Top side heatsink is the only option.  See pictures in my answer.

Comment: @Misunderstood you are right, it is not as simple as pouring copper. Bottom heatsink is also not an option as the space is usualy heavily populated with decoupling. But that only confirms main point of my comment - this is not a generic IC and it requires research to do cooling right. Not to mention thermal throttling and other tricks. Where I was wrong is in assumption that OP is trying to design a board for SoC, while the real question is simply about adding a heatsink to existing board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about maximum efficiency but there are little stick-on heatsinks that can reduce the junction temperature of BGA and LQFP packages.

I got like 90 of them (2 sizes) from Aliexpress for about $7 US shipped, but you can also find them at distributors. Chances are good the adhesive might be better in terms of longevity and thermal conductivity from the disties, but $$.

There are other options such as using a high tech thermal pad between the chip and a finned case, but there isn't so much advantage in that for the relatively low power levels and home/office environment. Chances are your SoC will be obsolete before it fails if you keep the junction temperature reasonable.

As others have said, most of the heat is typically conducted out through a thermal pad (with copious thermal vias on your board) to planes on the board. Keeping the board cool can be done with a fan, or perhaps something attached to the opposite side of the board (insulation is really important or something could be damaged).

Answer (score 2):

I think this processor calls for more than a little stick on heatsink.

The Exynos5422  has
2.1GHz Quad-Core (Cortex®-A15) +
1.4GHz Quad-Core (Cortex®-A7) +
Mali™-T628 MP6 GPU +
Video VP8 Codec +
WQXGA

---

**This is an image of two Exynos5422 boards.

This is the way to go, one active, one passive.**

[image]

---

**And for those with the idea of cooling from the bottom side,

this is why that may be problematic.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anything thermally conductive on the top of an IC can decrease thermal heating (with some thickness, aluminum foil probably won't work).

In the past I have taped on pieces of aluminum for prototyping with a dab of thermal compound, even a 1cm^2 bit of aluminum with no fins can decrease the temp of an SOIC by 20-30C (and keep it from burning up), because the surface area to air goes up substantially.